# Rust iterators and looking forward (peek/multipeek)

Tags: iteration, rust

I am trying to use a pattern with iterators in Rust and falling down somewhere, apparently simple.

I would like to iterate through a container and find an element with a predicate [A] (simple), but then look forward using another predicate and get that value [B] and use [B] to mutate [A] in some way. In this case [A] is mutable and [B] can be immutable; this makes no difference to me, only to the borrow checker (rightly).

It would help to understand this with a simple scenario, so I have added a small snippet to let folk see the issue/attempted goal. I have played with itertools and breaking into for/while loops, although I want to remain as idiomatic as possible.

**Silly Example scenario**

Lookup an even number, find next number that is divisible by 3 and add to the initial number.

```
#[allow(unused)]
fn is_div_3(num: &u8) -> bool {
    num % 3 == 0
}

fn main() {
    let mut data: Vec<u8> = (0..100).collect();

    let count = data.iter_mut()
        .map(|x| {
            if *x % 2 == 0 {
                // loop through numbers forward to next is_div_3,
                // then x = x + that number
            }
            true
        })
        .count();

    println!("data {:?}, count was {} ", data, count);
}
```

[playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=f8eeacace95d0e52fc1bb8cee880708b&version=stable&backtrace=0)

Comment: Is this what you want? https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e42f4ff5833f68a56fd4dfe5540992c0&version=stable&backtrace=0

Comment: Something like that would work, yes, thanks. I would like to be as idiomatic as possible though whilst altering the item at index1, possibly allowing iteration like this through the whole list/vec etc. Nice though.  If possible without direct access iters would be good. This would work for the situation I ma looking at though, easy to add another direct access and alter index1 position.

Comment: I've got something working without much indexing [on the playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=e42f4ff5833f68a56fd4dfe5540992c0&version=stable&backtrace=0) but it still is quite verbose. I think an iterator based on `split_at_mut` would be a more interesting building brick (an iterator that yields `(&mut [T], &mut [T])` with the boundary shifting at each iteration).

Comment: There's nothing wrong with just having a for or while loop, if it expresses what you want to do more clearly.  IMO a simple for-based loop is more idiomatic than a contorted solution with iterators!

Comment: That was just a silly example, there is no need to count at all.

Comment: There are some more useful answers to this question at https://users.rust-lang.org/t/rust-iterators-and-looking-forward-peek-multipeek/6138

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Warning: The iterator presented right below is `unsafe` because it allows one to obtain multiple aliases to a single mutable element; skip to the second part for the corrected version.** *(It would be alright if the return type contained immutable references).*

If you are willing to write your own window iterator, then it becomes quite easy.

First, the iterator in all its gory details:

```
use std::marker::PhantomData;

struct WindowIterMut<'a, T>
    where T: 'a
{
    begin: *mut T,
    len: usize,
    index: usize,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'a mut [T]>,
}

impl<'a, T> WindowIterMut<'a, T>
    where T: 'a
{
    pub fn new(slice: &'a mut [T]) -> WindowIterMut<'a, T> {
        WindowIterMut {
            begin: slice.as_mut_ptr(),
            len: slice.len(),
            index: 0,
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for WindowIterMut<'a, T>
    where T: 'a
{
    type Item = (&'a mut [T], &'a mut [T]);

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.index > self.len { return None; }

        let slice: &'a mut [T] = unsafe {
            std::slice::from_raw_parts_mut(self.begin, self.len)
        };
        let result = slice.split_at_mut(self.index);

        self.index += 1;

        Some(result)
    }
}
```

Invoked on `[1, 2, 3]` it will return `(&[], &[1, 2, 3])` then `(&[1], &[2, 3])`, ... until `(&[1, 2, 3], &[])`. In short, it iterates over all the potential partitions of the slice (without shuffling).

Which is safe to use as:

```
fn main() {
    let mut data: Vec<u8> = (1..100).collect();

    for (head, tail) in WindowIterMut::new(&mut data) {
        if let Some(element) = head.last_mut() {
            if *element % 2 == 0 {
                if let Some(n3) = tail.iter().filter(|i| *i % 3 == 0).next() {
                    *element += *n3;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    println!("{:?}", data);
}
```

Unfortunately it can also be used as:

```
fn main() {
    let mut data: Vec<u8> = (1..100).collect();

    let mut it = WindowIterMut::new(&mut data);
    let first_0 = { it.next(); &mut it.next().unwrap().0[0] };
    let second_0 = &mut it.next().unwrap().0[0];

    println!("{:?} {:?}", first_0 as *const _, second_0 as *const _);
}
```

which when run print: `0x7f73a8435000 0x7f73a8435000`, show-casing that both mutable references alias the same element.

---

Since we cannot get rid of aliasing, we need to get rid of mutability; or at least defer to *interior mutability* (`Cell` here since `u8` is `Copy`).

Fortunately, `Cell` has no runtime cost, but it does cost a bit in ergonomics (all those `.get()` and `.set()`).

I take the opportunity to make the iterator slightly more generic too, and rename it since `Window` is already a used name for a different concept.

```
struct FingerIter<'a, T>
    where T: 'a
{
    begin: *const T,
    len: usize,
    index: usize,
    _marker: PhantomData<&'a [T]>,
}

impl<'a, T> FingerIter<'a, T>
    where T: 'a
{
    pub fn new(slice: &'a [T]) -> FingerIter<'a, T> {
        FingerIter {
            begin: slice.as_ptr(),
            len: slice.len(),
            index: 0,
            _marker: PhantomData,
        }
    }
}

impl<'a, T> Iterator for FingerIter<'a, T>
    where T: 'a
{
    type Item = (&'a [T], &'a T, &'a [T]);

    fn next(&mut self) -> Option<Self::Item> {
        if self.index >= self.len { return None; }

        let slice: &'a [T] = unsafe {
            std::slice::from_raw_parts(self.begin, self.len)
        };

        self.index += 1;
        let result = slice.split_at(self.index);

        Some((&result.0[0..self.index-1], result.0.last().unwrap(), result.1))
    }
}
```

We use it as a building brick:

```
fn main() {
    let data: Vec<Cell<u8>> = (1..100).map(|i| Cell::new(i)).collect();

    for (_, element, tail) in FingerIter::new(&data) {
        if element.get() % 2 == 0 {
            if let Some(n3) = tail.iter().filter(|i| i.get() % 3 == 0).next() {
                element.set(element.get() + n3.get());
            }
        }
    }

    let data: Vec<u8> = data.iter().map(|cell| cell.get()).collect();

    println!("{:?}", data);
}
```

[On the playpen](https://play.rust-lang.org/?gist=b0eb7f3d1852a4bd78b6921ac5268a22&version=stable&backtrace=0) this prints: `[1, 5, 3, 10, 5, 15, 7, 17, 9, 22, ...]`, which seems correct.

Comment: @dirvine: I just realized that, unfortunately, this iterator is unsafe because it allows a user to obtain safely mutable aliases to the same element (if used outside the loop protocol). A fix would be to only return one mutable element (such as `(&mut T, &[T])`) for example.

Comment: Yes, the revised method does look though as though it is safe and I think also efficient? Well anyway as efficient as is currently possible. Very nice code Matthieu, this will help for sure. Neatest solution I can see.

Comment: @dirvine: Still unclear whether it's really safe, unfortunately. I just realized we still have aliasing + mutability unfortunately (even though only one of the alias allows mutability, it's still an issue...). In the end, I think to keep the spirit of the code the iterator would have to only return non-mutable references and the user would have to use `Cell` (or `RefCell` if necessary) to get by with interior mutability.

Comment: @dirvine: recorrected again, this time with `Cell`, same principle but lose a bit in aesthetics :/

Comment: Ah nice. I had not seen the improvement here with cell, of course it's more solid again.

Comment: @MatthieuM. You might be interested in [my take on this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/38810928/1763356).

Answer (score 7):

Sadly I'm a bit late, but here goes.

It's not totally pretty, but it's not as bad as the other suggestion:

```
let mut data: Vec<u8> = (1..100).collect();

{
    let mut mut_items = data.iter_mut();
    while let Some(x) = mut_items.next() {
        if *x % 2 == 0 {
            let slice = mut_items.into_slice();
            *x += *slice.iter().find(|&x| x % 3 == 0).unwrap();
            mut_items = slice.iter_mut();
        }
    }
}

println!("{:?}", data);
```

gives

```
[1, 5, 3, 10, 5, 15, 7, 17, 9, 22, ...]
```

as with Matthieu M.'s solution.

The key is to use `mut_items.into_slice()` to "reborrow" the iterator, effectively producing a local (and thus safe) clone of the iterator.